# An Android app remembers its data after uninstall and reinstall

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

While developing an Android app targeting all versions above 4.1, I observed that uninstalling my app and installing it again does not clear its data.

The app is designed to store the details that it asks in its first screen. 
 After uninstalling and installing again in OS version 4.4.4, the app prompts the user to fill in the data, which is normal.  However in version 6.0 the same install/uninstall sequence bring backs the data originally input.

I tried to ensure by visiting `/data/data/my package folder` to see the database is gone after uninstalling and indeed that folder gets deleted during uninstall.

I tried to delete the app by visiting the settings page, through Titanium Backup and the results are same. The device is rooted Nexus 5 running v6.0.

What could be the reason for this strange behavior?

Answer (score 453, accepted):

It's because Android 6 has automatic backup. You need to tune `android:allowBackup` and `android:fullBackupContent` in your manifest `<application>` tag if you don't want your data backed up or if you want to include or exclude some resources. It's not a bug.

More about AutoBackup on Android [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup).

Comment: This is the correct answer and it work for me (I had the same problem)
To avoid this behaviou is necessary to put

**android:allowBackup="false"** and  **android:fullBackupContent="false"**

in  manifest.xml

Comment: In case some of you wonder, android:allowBackup and android:fullBackupContent are properties to add in <application/>

Comment: From documentation: android:fullBackupContent points to XML file which contains backup options. By default, most of the files are backed up. 
Although settings this to "false" does not trigger any error, I guess it's wrong to set.

Comment: Not sure why did they keep default behaviour to take backup, as the behaviour is not in sync with previous versions so becomes annoying. Those who want it could turn it on.

Comment: in my case in ionic 2. after reinstalling the app it is not removing the items from storage. means that it is not clearing the storage.
I added these two lines but not working on my side.

Comment: @ShehramTahir Verify that no other plugin changes this setting back. Generally it could be observed also in logs during the build. I'm using cordova and these settings did make the change. You may also need https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config to affect AndroidManifest.xml from your config.xml

Comment: Even after setting `android:allowBackup` and `android:fullBackupContent` it is not deleting my app's package and all files are still their after uninstall. I am testing on Moto G4 Plus - Android 7.0

Comment: Maybe you need to start out the app with that flag set to false? Otherwise the backed up one will have that flag?

Comment: Anyone know how to delete the backups?

Comment: I think `FirebaseRemoteConfig` cause this issue. Because of the caching mechanism it provides, they probably have `fullBackupContent` declared in their own manifests.

Comment: What if I don't like that as a user? Can I somehow get rid of the data an app stores in the backup?

Comment: I got this situation in a Flutter App. I never heard about that  before... thank you very much!

Comment: @SARATH V I think only user can do that going to the backup section in Google Drive deleting the app data backup.

Comment: @greywolf82 is there any way to programatically disable restoring of data?

Comment: I don't think so, you can just adjust the flags in the manifest as explained in the answer.

Comment: @1800INFORMATION The backup is done on Google Drive through the Google Backup service that is on Android by default since Android M. I couldn't figure out the way to delete or replace the backups of my app specifically, but forcing a new FULL backup solved my issue.

Comment: How do I do the same in PWA apps ?

Comment: Thanks @Alber8295, 1800INFORMATION. This worked for me to solve this irritating problem from a user perspective: Uninstalled the app (that I want to use with another login but which would keep me logging in with the old user after installation), found option "Backup by Google One" on my Android device and started "Back up now". Installed the app again, after backup was finished. FINALLY, prompt for new user login.

Answer (score 58):

greywolf82's answer is correct but I want to add some info to this.

When developing my Android app (using Xamarin), I noticed that whenever I'd re-launch the app from Visual Studio, my data would revert back to data from a few months ago. It didn't matter if I simply stopped and re-ran it from VS, or if I completely uninstalled the app and reinstalled it.

It's also worth noting that we never explicitly told the app to store a backup.

The backup also seemed to overwrite newer data when launching from Visual Studio, and we have reports of users using the release build of our app and also getting newer data overwritten by the backups.

Since I don't know exactly when backups and restores occur this feature seems to cause only problems.

We've modified our AndroidManifest by adding the following two lines:

```
android:allowBackup="false"
android:fullBackupOnly="false"
```

After adding them, our AndroidManifest contained the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.XXXXXXX" android:versionName="8.0.0" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="439">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="24" />
    <application 
               android:label="@string/appName" 
               android:icon="@drawable/icon_small" 
               android:installLocation="internalOnly" 
               android:largeHeap="true"
               android:allowBackup="false"
               android:fullBackupOnly="false"
               />
...
</manifest>
```

Once we explicitly set the value to false, all seems to work. I'd expect this to be an opt-in feature but...seems like it might be on by default for apps which don't specify the value either way.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same issue.

Comment: Which parameters except the *Backup* ones did you add to solve it? Is "installLocation" related to this issue as well?

Comment: I find that this does work, but sadly the AndroidManifest gets regenerated by VS and these attribs get lost. I posted a follow-on question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68181172/

Answer (score 20):

You should check your device's Backup and Reset settings, and turn off Automatic restore (when reinstalling an application, backed up settings and data will be restored.)

Turning off auto-backup is different from the auto-restore. If you think it will be helpful to turn on auto-backup for your application do so. But if you think this will make end users who are not aware that the auto-restore feature of their device is turned on, feel free to turn it off.

In my case, I turned off the allowBackup feature, but since I already had a backup of the previous version on the Cloud, it still kept on restoring.

See image as reference for a Samsung device on Android 6.0. Other devices and versions may have a different screen. See image below.

[Automatic Restore Setting under Backup and Reset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rQfy.png)

Comment: I have the same issue, my app had backed up data for few users when it was on. Is there any possibility to clear/discard synced data?

Answer (score 9):

Just adding to this, we found that in Android 9 (on a HMD Nokia device) that the assets were held, even after deleting the app through the interface and through adb.

The answer of adding:

`android:allowBackup="false"
 android:fullBackupOnly="false"`

Obviously, this is not a new answer - but an observation for people who were in the same position as us.

Answer (score 7):

If you are targeting android 10 then you have to put `android:hasFragileUserData="true"` in application tag of `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hasFragileUserData="true">

    .....

     </application>

 </manifest>
```

> android:hasFragileUserData is a new manifest setting (I’m guessing on ). “If true the user is prompted to keep the app’s data on uninstall”. This seems ripe for abuse, but I can see where it might be useful for some apps.

See https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/06/random-musings-q-beta-4.html

Answer (score 7):

This answer summarizes multiple other existing answers, and includes recent details as of Android 12 being introduced, and includes instructions for clearing existing app backup data generated from a device.

For more information, see
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#EnablingAutoBackup
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#backup-restore
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element
http://android-doc.github.io/preview/backup/index.html (for clearing existing app backup data stored in Google Drive from a device: Settings > Backup > toggle Google One backup off then back on again, then try uninstall/reinstall again)

As a side note, some of the other answers suggest `android:fullBackupContent="false"` but that doesn't seem correct anymore since that is currently meant to specify an xml file of a specific format, not a true/false.

These attributes to `<application>` allow for disabling or configuring specifics for Android auto-backup functionality.

```
<application
tools:replace="android:label, android:icon, android:allowBackup, '...any other attribute you want to override with a value you set in this file for in case dependencies set them to other values...'"
'...your other attributes set here like android:label and android:icon...'
android:allowBackup="false" '...default is true, and setting this false prevents data backups of any kind (except device to device transfers if your app targets Android 11 (API 30) or higher)...'
android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules_android_11_and_below" '...optional, for Android 11 and below, referring to a file res/xml/backup_rules_android_11_and_below.xml you need to create...'
android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/backup_rules_android_12_and_above" '...optional, for Android 12 and above (fullBackupContent still needed along with this, assuming you support Android 11 and below), referring to a file res/xml/backup_rules_android_12_and_above.xml you need to create, with a slightly different required xml format...'
android:fullBackupOnly="false" '...optional, and default is false, but if set to true this field description says it enables auto backup on Android 6 (API 23) devices or higher (I am not sure how this matters compared to the more broadly reaching allowBackup)...'
android:hasFragileUserData="false" '...optional, and default is false, but if set to true this field description says it gives the user an option when they uninstall the app whether or not to backup their app data...'
>
'...contents of application element...'
</application>
```

The `<application>` changes only affect creation (or lack of creation) of future app backups; any existing app backup data will still exist and be used until overwritten or cleared (see above for instructions to clear that data for a device).

Comment: I enabled bio metric for my app and it's still enabled after uninstall the app.
Facing this issue in custom OS devices working fine with stock OS devices.
Please share me what is the issue  i allowed `android:allowBackup="true" in android manifest

Comment: @Arbaz.in  > (for clearing existing app backup data stored in Google Drive from a device: Settings > Backup > toggle Google One backup off then back on again, then try uninstall/reinstall again)

Answer (score 6):

I recently needed to take advantage of these features, I was able to uncover documentation and upon extensive testing  this is what I have been able to deduce:

Android:allowbackup - will backup local app data on the device it is located on.

Android:fullBackupContent - is used in conjunction with Google's backup restore api and CAN be controlled via an xml file to specify what exactly to backup, as well as a BackupManager class you may implement for further control over the process.

However the documentation states, and I have confirmed with testing, that a restore will only occur either when the device is restored and the restore app data process is triggered. OR it will also restore when the app is sideloaded through adb, which is what we do when we run the app for testing or debug on our devices through Android Studio. Note that if you set android:allowbackup but do not configure android:fullBackupContent with a Google api code then the apps data only gets stored locally, whereas if you configured it properly then if your app was backed up and you get a new device the apps data was stored on the cloud so it can be restored on a new device.

Answer (score 5):

Adding  android:allowBackup="false" under application tag in Manifest file solved my issue.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup) goes the android documentation for Back up user data with Auto Backup

Answer (score 5):

I also added:

```
tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
```

to override same option in a used component

Answer (score 4):

Just change android:allowBackup="true" to android:allowBackup="false" in manifiest.xml. It will be worked.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</manifest>
```

Comment: What will be the case for PWA ?