# SQLite data is being deleted when deploying same app from different computer

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two computers, each running Community Edition Visual Studio 2015.

Both machines are building a Xamarin Forms app from the same GitHub master.

Each machine can successfully install the Android application onto my Android phone.

Once installed, the app runs without problems.

Both machines are set to “Preserve application data cache on device between deploys”

The issue I’m having is with the SQLite database used by the app. If I install from either of the computers, the app works, and data can be saved. If I make a code change and redeploy from the same machine, the SQLite data is persisted.
However if I switch to the other machine for the next deploy, all the data disappears. From that point new data can be added, and as long as I stay with this other machine, new deploys do not cause loss of data. If I switch to the other machine, the next deployment deletes the data.

My question is this: How can I keep the SQLite database in place regardless of which computer was used for the deployment?

```
public class SQLiteService : ISQLiteService
{
    string GetPath(string databaseName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(databaseName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid database name", nameof(databaseName));
        }
        var sqliteFilename = $"{databaseName}.db3";
        var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqliteFilename);
        return path;
    }

    public SQLiteConnection GetConnection(string databaseName)
    {
        return new SQLiteConnection(GetPath(databaseName));
    }

    public long GetSize(string databaseName)
    {
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(GetPath(databaseName));
        return fileInfo != null ? fileInfo.Length : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Application data is probably getting wiped on re-install. That's the way your android device "might" be setup. If you make code changes that cause a re-deploy of the APK to your device, then the app essentially gets reinstalled. Are you pushing a pre-populated db from the Assets folder or are you creating it on the fly?

Comment: To further clarify... keep this in mind: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169618/an-android-app-remembers-its-data-after-uninstall-and-reinstall

App data doesn't always get flushed on re-install. But, it might depending on your settings.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll take a look at that link later when I get home. The data only gets wiped out if I re-install from the "other" machine. As long as I stay with the same machine, it is all good; the data stays.

Comment: @dev1988 If you switch between machines (between build/deploys), I would expect the entire app to get wiped / reinstalled unless you specify the setting I linked you. VS is going to see a different APK being pushed from a different machine (even if you didn't change anything, it's a different apk). As a best practice, I would expect an SQLite db to be wiped on a version upgrade / reinstall (don't assume users know how to prevent it).

Comment: @maplemale Thanks for the help. I looked at the link and I'll try to get the next change implemented in the next day or so. My database was added to my solution using this[https://wolfprogrammer.com/2016/09/10/adding-a-sqlite-database-to-xamarin-forms/]