# Firebase auth will skip login page even after reinstall the app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

For my android app I am using google firebase auth, the problem is after uninstall and reinstall the app it is still skip the login page and have the session, I am using android 7, I cleaned the backup according to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169618/an-android-app-remembers-its-data-after-uninstall-and-reinstall) by adding `android:allowBackup="false"` and `android:fullBackupContent="false"` in manifest.xml 
but it did not help. Any one can help on this?

Answer (score 1):

In the [Firebase Auth Quickstart sample code](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/GoogleSignInActivity.java), the sign-out for Google provider includes these steps. Make sure you calling Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut() along with firebase's .signOut() when you sign-out.

```
private void signOut() {
//Firebase
mAuth.signOut();

//Google
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
        new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                updateUI(null);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: I do not have any signout but it should not be normal practice when someone uninstall the app it does not sign in automatically when reinstall?

Comment: This was introduced by Google to improve the user experience.

Comment: What you need to research is how to prevent Google sign-in from auto-picking the user account.