# Firebase Auth SignOut not working on Uninstall

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Sign-in with Google method to sign-in a user in my app.

Problems - **Update**:

1. If I uninstall the app (after sign-out or without sign-out) and re-install the app, FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() comes non-null. So, the user gets access to the account.
2. I even tried by clearing the app data, the problem still exists.

The app was working fine before adding 'FirebaseInstanceIdService' and 'FirebaseMessagingService' services. Means, it was signing-out automatically after uninstalling.

**Manifest.xml**

```
    <meta-data   
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
    <meta-data android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
        android:value="false" />
    <meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
        android:value="false" />

....

<service
        android:name=".services.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".services.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

....
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.class**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MessagingService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(remoteMessage));
}
}
```

**MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class**

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

private static final String TAG = "InstanceIdService";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();

    if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null){
        return;
    }

    String tokenId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    saveTokenIdToDatabase(tokenId);
}
}
```

**signOutAccount method**

```
private void signOutAccount(){

FirebaseAuth.getInstance.signOut();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finishAffinity();
}
```

Comment: Are you using Smart Lock? If so, firebase automatically log in your Google account even if is a fresh install

Comment: try this `FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user == null) {
                    // user auth state is changed - user is null
                    // launch login activity
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };`

Comment: @GuilhermeFGL No smart lock. I haven't even changed my testing device. It is happening after I worked on FirebaseMessagingService

Comment: @D.'s No, it's not working.

Comment: can you please remove this `if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null){
        return;
    }`

Comment: @Eminem Still not working

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not the only one struggling with it. I had similar issue. After reinstalling (or updating) the app, in BaseActivity I checked if user is logged in. And he was.. `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` returned non-null value. So when I used the  `uid` to get data from firebase database I got a mess - some random items.

Also note, that I could reproduce it only **on some devices**. For examples, I got non-null value on *Nexus 5x* but not on *Oneplue 3t* (8.0.0).

After some investigation I found out several interesting facts.

**Fact #1** ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user))

> There are some cases where `getCurrentUser` will return a non-null
>   FirebaseUser but the underlying token is not valid.

In fact, when `getCurrentUser() != null` you can't be sure that user is actually signed in. My conclusion was, I can't rely on `getCurrentUser` and I should reconsider the way how I check if user logged in ([as an option](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)).

**Fact #2**

Android app sometimes remembers its data after reinstalling the app, because of
automatic backup. [See the post for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169618/an-android-app-remembers-its-data-after-uninstall-and-reinstall).

**Solution**

```
<application
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:fullBackupContent="false"
  ...>
```

I set `android:allowBackup` and `android:fullBackupContent` to false. So when I reinstall the app (or update it), firebase current user is `null`.

Comment: regarding Fact 1, immediately after firebase init, I awaited the get jwt method with force refresh = true. not sure the line in Android but in Flutter `await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.getIdToken(true);` this set current user to the correct state.