# Firebase Auth remembers the currentUser after signed out and relaunch the app

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

In this app, I have a logout button that's signed out the user if logged in with email & password or with a google account, the problem happens after signing out and re-launch the app again in the `SplashActivity`, I do check for the `currentUser` if is `null` it should go to the login page, else it should go to the home page, but It seems the app remember the current user even it's logged out before, I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50853560/4205927) but it doesn't work

**Gif describes the problem**

[image]

**the dagger hilt module**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideFirebaseAuth() = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideFirebaseFirestore() = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()


}
```

SplashActivity code

```
private const val TAG = "SplashActivity"
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SplashActivity  : AppCompatActivity() {



    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySplashBinding
    @Inject
    lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySplashBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.blacklist)

        val animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.my_anim)

        binding.apply {
            splashTextView.typeface = typeface
            splashTextView.animation = animation
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ${firebaseAuth.currentUser?.providerData?.get(0)?.email}")



    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({ /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */

            if(firebaseAuth.currentUser == null) {
                val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                this@SplashActivity.startActivity(intent)
                this@SplashActivity.finish()
            }else{
                val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, HomeActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                this@SplashActivity.startActivity(intent)
                this@SplashActivity.finish()
            }
        }, 3000)
    }
}
```

**ProfileFragment "logout button code"**

```
private const val TAG = "ProfileFragment"

@AndroidEntryPoint
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentProfileBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    @Inject
    lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

    private lateinit var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient

    private val viewModel by viewModels<CredentialsViewModel>()


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.logoutButton.setOnClickListener {


            val currentUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser ?: return@setOnClickListener

            for (i in 0 until currentUser.providerData.size) {
                when (currentUser.providerData[i].providerId) {
                    "google.com" -> {
                        //User signed in with a custom account
                        Log.d(
                            TAG,
                            "onViewCreated: provider is ${currentUser.providerData[i].providerId}"
                        )
                        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(
                            requireActivity(),
                            viewModel.getGoogleSignInOptions()
                        )

                        googleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener {

                            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                                redirectToMainActivity()
                            }else {
                                return@addOnCompleteListener
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    "password" -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: ${currentUser.providerData[i].providerId}")
                        firebaseAuth.signOut()
                        redirectToMainActivity()
                    }
                    else -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: ${currentUser.providerData[i].providerId}")
                        redirectToMainActivity()
                        return@setOnClickListener
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private fun redirectToMainActivity() {
        val intent = Intent(requireContext(), MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        startActivity(intent)
        requireActivity().finish()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code where you are using to sign out the user.

Comment: @alex-mamo already added check **ProfileFragment** code

Comment: Oh, yes, didn't see that. I will write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user is authenticated with email and password, in order to sign the user out, you only need to call:

```
firebaseAuth.signOut()
```

On the other hand, when you need to sign the user out from Google using:

```
googleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener { /* ... /* }
```

You're **only** singing out the user from Google. This operation doesn't sign out the user from Firebase automatically. So to sign the user out completely, you have to use:

```
firebaseAuth.signOut() //Sign out from Firebase
googleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener { /* ... /* } //Sign out from Google
```

Comment: but I already added code for signing out using "email & password" the code is in when the block, please check it

`"password" -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: ${currentUser.providerData[i].providerId}")
                        firebaseAuth.signOut()
                        redirectToMainActivity()
                    }`

Comment: Yes, but you should use `firebaseAuth.signOut()` also when you sign out from Google. Give it a try and tel me if it works.

Comment: I added `firebaseAuth.signOut()` before google signing out code and the problem is still persist

Comment: Does `googleSignInClient.signOut()` complete without no errors?

Comment: currently I tested signing out with (email & password) only

Comment: Try to use them separately and isolate the code so you can be sure that the signOut functions are triggered.

Comment: Hey Dr Mido. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: unfortunately, I tried to sign out with both methods like you said but the problem still persists, May I share the sample app on GitHub to check it out with more details?

Comment: When you have a lot of code, something may go wrong. That's why I suggested running those parts of the code in isolation. Besides that, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48862359/user-authentication-persisted-after-having-cancelled-the-user-from-console-fireb) out, if did that.