# Uninstalling a Codename One app doesn't remove all its data always

Tags: codenameone

I always assumed that when I uninstall a Codename One app (Android and iOS) all its data in the Storage and in the home path of the File System Storage is also cleaned... it seems so in my phones, but this is not the case on the Android phone of one of my friends (I'm referring to the same app developed by me).

Is there an explanation? Is it possible to be sure that all app data is cleaned during the app uninstalling? This is particularly useful during the software development.

Could this behavior be the one described in the answers to the question [An Android app remembers its data after uninstall and reinstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169618/an-android-app-remembers-its-data-after-uninstall-and-reinstall)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing here but it could be related to Android backup support which restores the data. Otherwise if you used `FileSystemService` and stored data in he SD card area that won't be removed on uninstall.

For the former we have a build hint: `android.allowBackup=false`

Comment: Thank you, about `FileSystemStorage`, I always used `getAppHomePath()` as root path for files: I suppose that this never gives a path to SD card, right? I'm going to try `android.allowBackup=false`. About iOS, can I assume that all app data is removed when I uninstall a Codename One app?