# Flutter Permission Request does not appear

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like that when it is the first time on the application, it asks the user if it can access the photos.

But when I uninstall the application to test, the application never asks me if it can access it. **It accesses it directly.**

**How resolve that ?**

```
if (await Permission.photos.request().isGranted) {
      //CODE
    }
```

AndroidManifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169618/an-android-app-remembers-its-data-after-uninstall-and-reinstall) helps you. Or try revoking permission in Android settings before you uninstall your app and check again.

Answer (score 0):

await Permission.photos.request(); use to ask permission