# Files appear in the Android/Data/{appName/} folder after installation, without starting the app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

So I am working on a Android app with Unity, and I use git (gitHub) for source control. The problem is that on my PC when I build the apk and install on a phone there are files in the Android/Data/{appName}/Files folder. That's a unexpected behaviour because I want to copy files there but only after starting the app. The interesting thing is that if I clone the repo and build the apk on my laptop it works fine, the files are only created on my phone when I start the apps and my own scripts copied them.

So my question is there a gradle or any build system configuration for this kind of behaviour? (I am not so familiar with gradle)

So basicly I tried going trough my git ignore list to find what can be the difference (the unity provided default on), but no luck.

Edit: The apks totally similiar, same size, etc

Answer (score 0):

Changing the product name in the player settings worked, but I am not convinced the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where old settings would appear immediately after installation, seemingly randomly.  In my situation it was because Android Auto Backup was restoring the files when the phone was online.  To stop this behavior, you have to add a couple lines to the Android Manifest.  If you are not using a custom Manifest, you can let Unity generate one:

1. Turn on:
   /Project Settings/Player/Publishing/Build/Custom Launcher Manifest
2. Build your project
3. Edit the LauncherManifest.xml that was just generated
4. Add to application tag:

   android:allowBackup="false"

   android:fullBackupOnly="false"
5. Re-build

Couple of useful links:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup

[An Android app remembers its data after uninstall and reinstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169618/an-android-app-remembers-its-data-after-uninstall-and-reinstall)