# installing flutter version application above an android version does not clears the cache on its own

Tags: android, flutter

installing  flutter version application above an android version does not clears the cache on its own. which results in change in profile if storage permissions are changed.

for eg in android version person A is logged in and if I install flutter version above it and login with person B's credential changing the permission it re-logins  person A automatically. which solves when
I clear the cache manually is there any other solution which can solve this without any manual changes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33176898/13973724